# Json.Net deserialization using setter Methods

Tags: c#, json.net

Using the following example is it possible to use the AddChild Setter method in Json.Net during Deserialization to populate the list of children?

```
public class Foo
{
    private IList<Foo> _children;
    private Foo _parent;

    public Foo()
    {
         _children = new List<Foo>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Children
    {
         get { return _children.AsEnumerable() }
    }

    public void AddChild(Foo child)
    {
         child._parent = this;
         _children.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom type converter by creating a concrete implementation of the `JsonConverter` class.